# get_template_directory_uri() and other URL tags not working in theme

Tags: theme-development, troubleshooting, bloginfo

So, I'm trying to add get_template_directory_uri or bloginfo() to my header.php file to create relative paths for the CSS and JS files in the theme.

E.g.,

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/style.css">
```

In theory this should show

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mysite.com/wp-content/themes/myTheme/css/style.css">
```

Problem is, when I view the `<head>` tag in source all I see is:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
```

All the other template tags work in my files (get_permalink(), the_title(), etc.), but this one isn't. `echo get_bloginfo('url')` Also works.

I was thinking of messing with the `wp-config.php` file and doing something like:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com/blog');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com/blog');
```

...but, I'm not sure if that's the best practice for rewriting the URL.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/style.css">
```

*should* work fine. I've copied and pasted into my `header.php` and it worked.

**But** this is **not** how you should be including css or javascript files. The proper way is to use the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook. For instance, say you have javascript file you wish to load which requires jQuery to work, you enqueue the script and list jQuery as a dependency.  WordPress does the rest:

```
<?php
function my_scripts_method() {
   // register your script location and dependencies
   wp_register_script('custom_script',
       get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom_script.js',
       array('jquery')
    );
   // enqueue the script
   wp_enqueue_script('custom_script');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
?>
```

For styles (the same hook is used):

```
function my_styles_method() {  
    // Register the style like this for a theme:  
    wp_register_style( 'my-custom-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/custom-style.css');  

    // enqueue the stule  
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my-custom-style' );  
}  
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_styles_method' );
```

Please read this Codex pages on and [`wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) and [`wp_enqueue_style()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style)

It may not seem important, but particularly with loading scripts, you'll probably find that loading them 'manually' will break your theme and/or plug-ins.

Comment: I didn't even know that existed. I will definitely migrate my code to this method shortly. My current issue is trying to understand why `<?php get_template_directory_uri() ?>` returns empty.

Comment: Have you `var_dump`ed it?

Comment: I am unfortunately unfamiliar with `var_dump` in WordPress. Could you clarify?

Comment: It's [not WordPress](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php):  `var_dump(get_template_directory_uri());`

Comment: Sorry, what I mean to say I don't know how to `var_dump` and read the output in WordPress. I assume just calling it in header.php won't give me what I'm looking for. I do appreciate your help though.

Comment: Yeah it will print the contents. If it's you do it in header you'll probably have to hunt around for it in the html of the page (it maybe inside `<head>`)

Answer (score 2):

A bit late on this but I just ran into the same issue. My problem was I had changed out all my theme files with an empty starter template theme and did not go through the theme's install steps so it was not getting the correct directory. Re-activating the theme might be an appropriate first step in finding a solution to this problem.

Comment: I've run into the same thing before - in my case, `get_template_directory_uri()` was returning the *child* theme, not the parent, which is of course the exact opposite of what it's supposed to do. swapping to the parent theme, and then switching back again to the child completely cleared it up for me.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the simple version of bloginfo aka:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url); ?>/css/style.css" />
```

or you can use your version (meaning get_bloginfo) but i think you
should assign it to a var and the echo it..

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php $turl = get_bloginfo('template_url); echo tulr; ?>/css/style.css" />
```

...

Hope this helps tto solve your problem...

Best regards, Sagive.

Comment: Hey Sagive,

Thanks for the reply.

Unfortunately, neither of your suggestions work. It's still creating URLs relative to "mysite.com" instead of "mystie.com/wp-content/themes/myTheme/"

I'll keep messing around and see if I can figure something out.

Comment: My pleasure - got it working ?

Comment: Actually, [`get_bloginfo( 'template_url' )` itself just calls `get_template_directory_uri()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-includes/general-template.php#L443), so the *simpler* method is just to use `get_template_directory_ur()` directly.

Comment: @ChipBennett I agree. It's just for whatever reason, my site on this install doesn't call `get_template_directory_uri()` properly. I was hoping someone had experienced something similar.

Comment: i see no difference :) - bloginfo is on my snippet list so.. i prefer it... say @aboutaaron You mean to say its still not working ?

Comment: @SagiveSEO That is correct. `<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>` prints nothing! I've never seen this before. It worked fine on my dev version and then when I moved the them the URLs broke and for whatever this isn't working now.

Comment: @SagiveSEO that's the *point*: if `echo get_template_directory_uri()` isn't working, then it is **impossible** for `bloginfo( 'template_url' )` to work as an alternative. (See the core reference I linked.)

Comment: @aboutaaron did you get it working? I have the same problem. get_stylesheet_directory_uri() and get_template_directory_uri() returns empty string.

Comment: if you get empty string than that page where you are using the command in isnt inside wordpress... This is an inner WP command and should work without a hitch: get_template_directory_uri()  OR get_bloginfo('template_url') - which file are you using this in?

Answer (score 0):

if the get_bloginfo('url') is working in header.php then Instead of using get_template_directory_uri(); use bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); function which Returns the primary CSS (usually style.css) file URL of the active theme.

Answer (score 0):

Deactivate the current theme (ie. activate a different theme, say TwentyFourteen) and then reactivate your theme.

When a theme is activated WordPress goes through some initial set-up of relative uri's, etc. and there are sometimes cases (particularily new theme development) where WordPress does not run that initialization code.  Deactivating and reactivating the theme makes sure that WordPress gets another chance at running the theme initialization set-up.